# Why does Google Maps Display Routes/Waypoints Differently on Phone than on PC?

Tags: email, google-maps, google-maps-navigation

And how do I fix it?

I am trying to display a specific route between my origin and destination, rather than letting google maps choose the route.  So, I create the route in google maps on my PC and then email the route to myself so that I can open it on my phone.  For example:

[image: Google Maps Result from PC]

Note the white circles on the blue route indicating that I have dragged the route away from its default.

The link is:

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=22202&daddr=38.902418,-77.069841+to:38.908511,-77.053798+to:38.9456351,-77.0422782+to:39.00056,-77.03989+to:39.0174369,-77.0432333+to:20902&hl=en&sll=39.004912,-77.02652&sspn=0.089509,0.183506&geocode=FTzOUAIduXlo-yk34EFN2La3iTFBkycb6n588Q%3BFZKaUQId7wFo-yktwDKhRba3iTFCpG9KdYsdWw%3BFV-yUQIdmkBo-ym5an6ntbe3iTFJCATBLUUQZA%3BFWNDUgIdmm1o-ymfOuDwOMi3iTEfD6EAX58b7A%3BFfAZUwId7nZo-ykh5TBQz8i3iTHdODB7bMR3-g%3BFdxbUwId32lo-yn38LS2Mc-3iTEUl-sEkNiw-Q%3BFS7IUwIduXlo-ymj3f5RBc-3iTHt3MhgKrzmqQ&mra=dpe&mrsp=4&sz=13&via=1,2,3,4,5&t=m&z=13

When I click on the link on my phone and ask that it be opened in google maps (as opposed to the browser), I get the following result:

[image: Google Maps from PC Link Opened on Phone]

Clicking through the waypoints using the arrows at the bottom of the map, it seems like when I hit the 14th waypoint, the position of the waypoint jumps onto a previous waypoint, even though the text of the directions remains correct.  I haven't been able to discern a pattern to this remapping.

Why does this happen?  Is there a way to avoid it?

Note: I am using a Droid Bionic running Android 2.3.4.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Does this happen when you search for directions within the Maps app?

Comment: To answer Chahk, this does not happen when I search for directions from within the Maps app, but I cannot specify a route by dragging Google's suggested route to the route I prefer (like I can on an PC).  I find that Google Maps is very good at getting me where I'm going, but I'm better at optimizing a route for my daily commute.  I'm doing the above to force Google to give me a traffic prediction for the route that I intend to take.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, according to Google's [official post](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2011/03/youve-got-better-things-to-do-than-wait.html), Maps on the phone take real time traffic conditions into account when calculating directions.  This could explain the discrepancies between the directions you found via PC earlier.

The bug you are describing could be a side-effect of this, when Navigation is trying to be too smart for its own good, and the route from web is confusing the computation of real-time directions.  I would submit this as a bug report to Google.

Comment: How do I submit a bug report to Google?

Comment: I couldn't find where to file actual bug reports.  Posting on the Google Maps forum would probably be the next best option.  https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!forum/maps

Comment: Thank you, Chahk.  I have copied this post to the [Google Maps Forum](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/maps/issues-and-troubleshooting/maps/mobile-android/mobile-app/YMwpPBNnNlU)